# Dynamic table view height

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]

The idea is to resize height of the cell automatically based on few controls heights. As you can see on image above I have **Top Label** and **Bottom Label**. These two labels can have different height based on text length.

Few words about setup in storyboard.

I set number of lines to 0 for 2 described labels to allow grow their height dynamically based on given text.

For the **Top Label** I have next constraints:

[image]

For the **Bottom Label** I have next constraints:

[image]

So I we say about vertical spacing between 1000 green label and bottom label it's every time the same:

[image]

But without this spacing cell won't stretch height. How can I reduce this vertical spacing? Because there is to much spacing between "1000 green label" and bottom label in case if top label have big height because of text.

In `-viewDidLoad` method I set:

```
[self.theTableView setEstimatedRowHeight:145];
[self.theTableView setRowHeight:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];
```

Seems it works pretty cool sometimes with a bug described here but I don't know how to restrict that vertical spacing:

http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32063950/4151918) will work around that "bug" mentioned in the tutorial, where they suggest to `reloadData`.

Comment: @PetahChristian, reload data does not work for me

Comment: If you set the width, you won't need to use reloadData.  If the cell is still not laid out properly, even after scrolling or reloadData, it indicated a problem with the constraints.  What you're trying to do is slightly complex.  You have a "left" portion and a "right" portion, and the taller of the two would determine the cell's actual height.  So the left and the right portions both have to have a >= constraint, so they can expand, if the other side is taller than they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the bottom label's top constraint to be >= 11.5 (or whatever its minimum spacing should be).

This will let the cell adjust that vertical spacing, depending on the other content in the cell.

**Update:**

In iOS 9, this would much more simply be handled by `UIStackView`.

A horizontal stack view would constrain (and determine the cell height based on the) two inner vertical stack views. The left vertical stack would handle the image, banner, and label layout, and the right vertical stack would handle the top label, 10000, and bottom label layout.  You'd only need with 4 constraints (for the horizontal stackView to constrain it to the contentView).